# Nuxt server api to be called by a react client

Tags: reactjs, nuxt.js

Hi is it possible to make Nuxt as my server and react as client. And call the nuxt rest api from react application ?

What are the thing I need to take care while doing it ?

Comment: You can use nginx to proxy the nuxt RESTful API routes

Comment: You could use Nitro for the backend stuff without bringing Nuxt. But overall Next probably has enough stuff for you to do some backend stuff. A serverless/edge function could also fill that job well IMO.